# Connectivity check from Windows host to Linux

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

How can I check the connectivity from Windows host to Linux host? In Linux we use `nc` command. Do we have any equivalent for that, either in PowerShell or cmd?

Command in Linux:

```
nc -vz IP PORT
```

I need similar command for cmd or PowerShell.

Comment: [`Test-NetConnection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/nettcpip/test-netconnection?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Test-NetConnection is not available. Will ping consider ACL also?

Comment: The name of the other cli in windows is `cmd`, not `dos`.

Answer (score 1):

From PowerShell.
If you just want to test TCP port and have Net 4.5 you could use something like;

```
$i = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient; $i.ConnectAsync(IP, PORT); $i.Connected; $i.Close()
```

for earlier versions the following simpler true / false version should work.

```
$i = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient; $i.Connect(IP, PORT); $i.Connected; $i.Close()
```

Otherwise use **POWERCAT** which is a non native add on function which has netcat like functionality by using native PowerShell version 2 components. First you need to load the function before you can execute it. find and installed it from here https://github.com/besimorhino/powercat

As mentioned in earlier comments For Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2, Microsoft released with Powershell 4. the cmdlet **Test-NetConnection** which can be use to troubleshoot network connection issues. Unfortunately this uses unique methods not available in earlier OS.

Also available **Test-Port** script https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/97119ed6-6fb2-446d-98d8-32d823867131#content